# how can I get the source code (html) of a page in C?

Tags: html, c, eclipse

how can I get the source code (html) of a page in C?
I need external libraries?
I read a library (libcurl), which is right for me
or is there some function that no other libraries should I download?

Comment: Including content that got created by Javascript?

Comment: that is? I need only get the html, and then work with strings for one exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task string.h library will be enought.This library contains alot of functions which will help you to work with strings of your html page.

Your algorithm:
1. You are calculate quantity of characters in HTML file;
2. Allocate array;
3. Read file into array;
4. Work with your array;

Comment: This will work only if the file is local. Otherwise, an exernal library like libcurl is needed.